# Magento - Show shipping methods by default on cart page

Tags: magento

I'd like to show available shipping methods on the Magento cart page, all the time.

I have a Magento 1.8.1 store that uses destination-independent shipping methods.  The price of shipping is the same no matter where the products are being shipped.  By default, Magento requires some elements of a destination address before it will show the shipping methods.  I'd like to show the shipping methods by default on the cart page.

Anyone solve this one already?

Comment: you need to add a country by default for all shipping methods you want to show always

Comment: @KingshukDeb - I'm not clear on what your referring to.  Is this an answer?

Comment: YES..you need to add default country to shipping methods..shipping methods basically work on destination. So set a default country for shipping options which will not show on frontend.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. I'm not clear what you're recommending.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want the selection of the shipping method within the cart or just adding the costs of (the first) shipping method (and so a preselection)?

Comment: I'd like to show the selection within the cart, without having to specify a destination location beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

here is a module that add a drop down to the cart totals on cart page select available shipping method and it will update the price of the cart.

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-shipping-method-dropdown-default-shipping-method-on-cart-page

the source code of the module is also available.